# can I do hash.has_key?('video' or 'video2') (ruby)

Tags: ruby, hash

or even better can I do **`hash.has_key?('videox')`** where x is

- '' nothing or
- a digit?

so 'video', 'video1', 'video2' would pass the condition?

of course I can have two conditions but in case I need to use video3 in the future things would get more complicated...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the general case of *video* followed by a digit without explicitly listing all the combinations there are a couple of methods from [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) that you could use in combination with a regular expression.

`hash.keys` is an array of the keys from `hash` and `^video\d$` matches video followed by a digit.

```
# true if the block returns true for any element    
hash.keys.any? { |k| k.match(/^video\d$/ }
```

or

```
# grep returns an array of the matching elements
hash.keys.grep(/^video\d$/).size > 0
```

`grep` would also allow you to capture the matching key(s) if you needed that information for the next bit of your code e.g.

```
if (matched_keys = hash.keys.grep(/^video\d$/)).size > 0
  puts "Matching keys #{matched_keys.inspect}"
```

Furthermore, if the prefix of key we're looking for is in a variable rather than a hard coded string we can do something along the lines of:

```
prefix = 'video'
# use an interpolated string, note the need to escape the
# \ in \d
hash.keys.any? { |k| k.match("^#{prefix}\\d$") }
```

Comment: hash.keys.any?(&blk) is the perfect solution for this. You can check almost any condition in the block, whether a string has a certain structure ( { |k| k.match(/^video\d$/ }
 ), whether an object of a certain class is a key ( { |k| k.is_a?(Numeric) } ), ...

Comment: @mikej: I like the way you explain everything... could you please also add to your answer how the code would look like if we use variable name instead of the actual string 'video'?. Thank you

Comment: @Radek updated the answer to show a case of where the prefix is in a variable. Hope this is the kind of thing you had in mind.

Comment: I figured the syntax for variable but with bit of troubles. I thought the answer could be perfect for other .... Thank you for great job!

Answer (score 6):

One possibility:

```
hash.values_at(:a, :b, :c, :x).compact.length > 1
```

Comment: @DigitalRoss: where :a,:b ect would be video, video1 etc?

Comment: Right, and at some point (1.9?) Array got an `abbrev` method which really does exactly what you want. I think that would go something like `hash.keys.abbrev 'video'`